# Kotlin: How to implement in kotlin an asynchronous socket connection with asynchronous read method and end-of-read callback method?

Tags: c#, android, sockets, kotlin, porting

Currently my android app communicates with a server via tcp socket with synchronous read and write methods

```
    private val addressString : String = "192.168.1.200"
    private val port : Int = 33322
    private var socketAddress: InetSocketAddress = InetSocketAddress(addressString, port)
    private var socket: Socket? = null
    
    fun connect(){
        socket = Socket()
        socketAddress = InetSocketAddress(addressString, port)
        try{
                socket!!.connect(socketAddress)
        }catch(e : Exception){
              socket!!.close()
        }
    }
    
    fun disconnect(){
         try {
            socket?.shutdownOutput()
        } catch (e: Exception) {}
        try {
            socket?.shutdownInput()
        } catch (e: Exception) {}
        try {
            socket?.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {}
        socket = null
    }
    
     fun send(data: ByteArray): Int {
        var sentByteCount: Int = -1
        try {
            socket!!.getOutputStream().write(data)
            sentByteCount = data.size
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
        return sentByteCount
    }
    
    data class Wrapper<T>(
    var value:T
)
    
      fun receive(buffer: Wrapper<ByteArray>): Int {
        val size = buffer.value.size
        var receivedByteCount: Int = -1
        try {
            receivedByteCount = socket!!.getInputStream().read(buffer.value)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
        return receivedByteCount
    }
```

However, the server, written in C#, always communicates with another device via socket but with an asynchronous reading method

```
 public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

            private string addressString = "192.168.1.200"
            private int port = 33322
            private int timeout = 5000
            private byte[] _buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            private TcpClient _client;
            private SocketError _socketError;
            private AsyncCallback _callback = new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback);
            
            public void connect()
            {
              _client = TCpClient()
              _client.ConnectAsync(addressString, port).Wait(timeout)
            }
            
            public void receive()
            {
                _client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, _socketError, _callback, null)
            }
            
            private void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                //callback method when it has finished reading asynchronously
            }
            
            public void send()
            {
                 _client.GetStream().Write(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
            }
            
            public void disconnect()
            {
                if (_client.Connected)
                 _client.Close();
            }
```

What I need is to communicate between my app and the device as the Server is already doing.

I tried to find out if even in kotlin there was the possibility of creating an asynchronous connection that would give me the possibility of being able to do an asynchronous reading as it can be done in C # and I found AsynchronousSocketChannel.
From the documentation, however, it has been deduced that the possibility of using this socket is linked to the fact that the server is an AsynchronousServerSocketChannel socket, in my case it is not possible to use it as I can only create the client.
Are there any other possibilities to recreate something similar to the C # code shown above in Kotlin?

Comment: `AsynchronousSocketChannel` is a general usage socket, you can use it however you want. You probably misread its docs. Its description says `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` is one way to acquire a socket. Another is using `connect()`. But I agree, this description is really misleading.

Comment: from the documentation it seemed that an AsynchronousSocketChannel should be used for the clients while an AsynchronousServerSocketChannel should be used for the server
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel

Comment: Yes, I read this documentation and I already addressed your concerns in my last comment, didn't I? :-) Again: you misunderstood this documentation. It does not say that `AsynchronousSocketChannel` is used to connect to `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` exclusively. It says that one way to acquire `AsynchronousSocketChannel` is when connection is made to `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel`. This sentence refers to server side, not to client side. `AsynchronousSocketChannel` is a regular "raw" socket as in any other socket library - just try it and see it for yourself.

Comment: Also, what is the main reason you need to do this asynchronously? I ask because Kotlin supports coroutines, it is a big deal in Kotlin world and preferred approach is to use suspend functions (so synchronous, but non-blocking).

Comment: because i'm porting a library written in c #